# How to define parameter name with @ArraySchema

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

I want to describe one query parameter using spring and swagger.
ReceiptStatus is an enum.
I expected `arrayschema` in @ArraySchema to be used

> to define the properties to be resolved into properties of the schema
> of type `array`

as per the documentation: https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.2.10/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/ArraySchema.html

Apparently name is not used to define parameter name.

```
@ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(description = "Status of the receipt", name = "status", example = "paid"))
private List<ReceiptStatus> statuses;
```

results in a parameter of type array with name statuses

and

```
@Schema(description = "Status of the receipt", name = "status", example = "paid")
private List<ReceiptStatus> statuses;
```

results in a parameter of type string with name status.

Is there a way to define a List of Enum and use a custom parameter name?